# Who was the composer of the music of Cyberlords: Arcology?

Tags: cyberlords-arcology

[Cyberlords: Arcology is a 2010 game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hg.cyberlords) for Symbian (and later, Android) mobile phones, made by Handy Games.

I could not find any actual credits about this game, so I'd like to ask, maybe someone may have an answer: who made the soundtrack of this game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sent an inquiry to the publishing studio, HandyGames GmbH, using their [contact form](http://company.handy-games.com/index.php?action=contact) and asked them who composed their music. This is their reply:

> Hi
>
> Thanks for your feedback!
>
> The music was created by our own musicians in house
>
> So unfortunately you can’t get it anywhere
>
> We have the theme online on our Facebook jukebox though.
>
> https://www.facebook.com/handygames/app_178091127385
>
> Thank you.
>
> Bye

My guess is that they either have no specific records of who worked on the piece, or it was a sufficiently collaborative composition that credits more specific than just "HandyGames" may not be accurate. If you really wanted to press for individual names responsible, you could send a further inquiry via the same [contact form](http://company.handy-games.com/index.php?action=contact).

Comment: Somehow, I didn't get an answer when I tried to contact with them. It was expectable anyway, I just wanted to listen to some similarly great cyberpunk songs. It seems that I have to wait for a sequel, or anything. After all, thanks for helping!